# Duplicate Close message sends wrong message to users

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Similar to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238520/should-the-closed-as-duplicate-message-be-altered).

I was helping a user (through comments) with a question, and I believe a question was closed as a dupe for a wrong reason. Then, I read the message:

[image]

So, we already established there was a question, possibly even a very similar question, but we want to encourage the user to **ask a new question**? This seems backwards, and a great way to earn users the ability to either learn to ask, or to mess up and ask ANOTHER question that may get closed.

I propose that it changes to say to edit the question to include more details. For example, maybe it's a problem with Product A on Platform B, but the duplicate is for Product A ver 2 on Platform C? I believe it could help users make constructive edits to their content on their own, and hopefully reopen the questions *not* as a duplicate, if done correctly.

Comment: I've wondered about this myself many a time. It also suggests that there's no way to recover that question if it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup, you're right. Maybe I can edit my question to say something more constructive :P JK.

Comment: @CanadianLuke yup, you can add your own vote. :)