# Is there a way / is it okay to bump feature requests?

Tags: discussion, support, bump, feature-request-process

I've made [a couple](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240466/make-magic-link-descriptions-clearer) of [feature requests](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240260/add-magic-link-for-mcve) that haven't had any response from SE in a couple of months. Trivial things that would make working on the sites easier on a day-to-day basis.

Is there a way, and is it okay to, bump things that seem to have been overlooked after a couple of months?

Comment: Related: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - That's backward, surely? As this post predates [that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without) by more than three years. Not that it particularly matters, but it does say *"This question has been asked **before**..."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the newer version is more general, and more faq-like, plus got a more detailed answer. So even that it's newer, it better fits as the "root". Nothing wrong in this being closed, people can still see it, it's still useful. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: True, timing isn't everything. :-) That message needs fixing. (Pleased to see [a request to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238520/should-the-closed-as-duplicate-message-be-altered), unfortunate such a trivial thing hasn't gotten done in nearly four years.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do three things:

- start a bounty
- mention my request in chat, SE devs are often there
- edit my post (to improve something, not *just* to bump)

I don't think there are other variants.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, a user started a bounty on one of them several days ago; I just started one on another. I can't really think of any edits that wouldn't just be for bumping...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the bounties will effectively bump them as they will get more attention than a single edit.  But don't assume that the attention will automatically bring a response from SE.  Many feature requests will tend to just sit until they get a `status-*` tag