# How can I tell if a developer has read my feature request?

Tags: discussion, feature-request-process

I posted a feature request in the boorish forum called `meta.math.stackexchange.com`. It was closed as a duplicate of a question that was *not* a feature request.

I do not suspect anyone who participated in its closing or who commented on it of being responsible for software development on Stack Exchange.
Is there any way to address a feature request to responsible persons and get a businesslike reply (or maybe even a polite reply)?

Comment: Boorish. Yeah. Very constructive.

Comment: You should demand a refund!

Comment: ha ha ha ha.  Generally people posting on math.stackexchange.com are polite or at least businesslike, except when engaging in the institutionalized rudeness that is built into the software in the form of certain boilerplate notices that I've mentioned there.  But then the go over to meta and they throw tantrums.  Those tantrums may be relatively harmless since there's not a lot of newbie-biting in them, but that boilerplate notice is cruelty to newbies and drives them away.

Comment: @2mkgz : Please be explicit.

Comment: Maybe a private message system would sort this out...

Comment: What a boorish tantrum.  I believe I shall register my disapproval.

Comment: So if I say that a certain standard practice is wrong and should be changed, then that behavior of mine constitutes a boorish tantrum?

Answer (score 14):

You're considerably less likely to get an official response to your feature-request if it isn't well-received by others first. We try to take our lead from the folks *using* these sites; if folks don't want a feature implemented, we're not in any great hurry to consider doing so.

If a feature *does* garner some significant amount of support, we'll try to leave an answer or comment that outlines our plans to implement it or - if implementation is not feasible - our reasons for ignoring it. That said, there are always more awesome features being requested than there is time to implement them, so it may take a significant amount of time for us to get around to reviewing them.

In your specific case, the feature you're requesting was both unpopular and had already been discussed at length in the past. It's unlikely anyone on the team will bother to comment on it.

Comment: You two beat me to the finish...

Comment: Is there any way to draw attention to a year old FR?

Comment: @Pandya http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244699/is-there-a-way-is-it-okay-to-bump-feature-requests