# Mark as repeated question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

We all know the phenomenon that OPs repeat their question when they don't get answers on the first one. When I see this, [I mark as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27463934/861716), but then this text is tacked to the question:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Well, the problem is, the first question doesn't have an answer (that's exactly the OP's problem) and the last thing I want them to do is ask a new question!

Could we have the option when we mark as duplicate, to indicate that the question is a repetition? A repeated question should have a text that encourages the OP to edit the original question.

Comment: I prefer to simply ditch the "already has an answer" in case there are no answers. OP sees a different banner already, as explained in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167270/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard But then they will still feel legislated to ask a new question.

Comment: True, but adding whole new mechanism is a huge overkill in my opinion. Changing to what Kate Gregory suggested in the other question should "solve" this as well, without complicating the system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, better, and I could live with that if my suggested change is overly complicated. I'd still prefer them to edit the original question though, because that doesn't need reopening.

Comment: Darn! Duplicate! Wait, I'm gonna ask again....