# Can we change the wording of the "marked as duplicate" template?

Tags: feature-request, bug

Can we change the wording of the "marked as duplicate" template?

[image]

I don't think we should say "ask a new question".

If the cited answers actually don't fully address my question, but that fact isn't clear (as opposed to someone did some hasty tagging without seeing that my question is different) then I should **fix my question to make it clear**, not leave a useless question hanging around and ask another.

Instead of "please ask a new question", it should say "please edit your question to make it clearer".

Comment: See this answer, OP sees suggestion to "edit" before they see "ask new": http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167270/230506

Comment: @James thanks, I note that, and actually I think it's pretty strange that the rest of the community, although understanding the text to be directed to the OP, don't see that part and hence are not aware of it! Regardless of whether others would be likely to edit the question, I think it would make more sense to just show the whole text of the message to everyone. (Or, if preferred, omit the entire last sentence.)